# Conditional Calculations for field entries within Wordpress using PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, conditional-statements, field

I was wondering if anyone with some experience with PHP could help. I've been trying to figure out if there is a way within WordPress (GravityView) to make calculations based on certain entries within a form and then use conditional logic to display different images dependent on the result from this calculation.

In this case, I am trying to display different images relating to different measures of a client, i.e. their value to our company, their engagement with our company. Taking the example of Satisfaction I have added a field to one of our forms where if a request is completed unsuccessfully with them it will count that entry. However, I then need to sum all these unsuccessful entries so I can relate them to the different levels of satisfaction (the images). i.e if there are 10 unsuccessful entries for a given client they will be given a poor level of satisfaction and if there are 0 they would be given an excellent level of satisfaction. This is not possible to do within a view in gravity view as you cannot use a shortcode within a shortcode. I cannot sum all the entries using [gvmath] for a specific field and then use [gvlogic] to assign the different levels to different images. So I was wondering if there is a way to bypass this by issue by writing the code directly in PHP.

Also, another issue is within the form that is used for the requests there is a field where the member ID is inserted. Each of our individual clients is given a specific member ID and then a page is created for that client where their 'Levels' are displayed. So ideally the PHP code would be able to sum the entries for only that specific member ID and then using the result of that calculation assigns a particular image to it depending on the answer. Is this all getting too complicated and not able to be performed within WordPress? I've been trying to wrap my head around it all week so any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've attached a picture of the specific images that I would like to assign to the different levels.

Let me know if any further context to my issue is required.
Thanks :)

[Levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V73cR.png)

Comment: Do you have some example code or scenario which you tried?

Comment: No one can read this whole statement.

Comment: I haven't tried inserting any of my own code yet as I really have never done any work in PHP, but as far as I'm aware it may look something like this. Not too sure how to adapt this to suit my example: https://docs.gravityview.co/article/235-making-calculations-using-the-custom-content-field

Comment: Please, avoid asking general questions about development approach. This site is intended for code support.